# Compute monthly mean of numpy array?

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I have two csv files with daily data spanning from 1950-1990 and columns as shown below:

file1:

```
year  month day value
1950    2   27  1.693   
1950    2   28  0       
1950    3   1   0.016   
1950    3   2   0.067
```

file2:

```
1950    2   27  0
1950    2   28  0.08
1950    3   1   0.05
1950    3   2   0
```

I want to take monthly mean of column 4 in both files. If monthly mean value in file1 is below 0.01 then write two new arrays (daily values with monthly mean > 0.01 and < 0.01). Also, use index of newly created arrays to create two new arrays of file2. I am trying with following which instead of monthly mean returns last daily value of array:

```
import numpy as np
import csv

time = [] ; f1 = [] ; f2 = []
with open('file1.csv','rb') as csvfile:
    reader=csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        time.append(row[1])
        f1.append(row[3])

with open('file2.csv','rb') as csvfile:    
    reader=csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        f2.append(row[3]) 

f1_arr = np.array(f1)
f2_arr = np.array(f2)
x = f1_arr.astype(np.float) # convert string to float
y = f2_arr.astype(np.float)
for ii in xrange(len(time)):
    if ii == ii:
        monthly_mean = np.mean(x[ii])
```

Please suggest how to fix it and separate arrays.

Comment: if you want the mean value of the fourth column, shouldn't it be `for ii in f1_arr` ?

Comment: I think to have time dimension in `for` loop and conditionally (if same month) take mean of values of specific month